# notifyDataSetChanged() on my adapter does not update the listview, why?

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, notify, baseadapter

I have a activity that extends listactivity, extended in this class i have a class that extends baseadapter.

now in my listactivity i have this onCreate

```
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new BuildingAdapter(this));

    final ProgressDialog loading = new ProgressDialog(this);
    loading.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    loading.setTitle("Laddar");
    loading.setMessage("Hämtar data från servern");
    loading.show();

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, DataPacket.Data>()
    {
        @Override
        protected DataPacket.Data doInBackground(Void... params){
            return ServerConnection.getBuildings();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(DataPacket.Data param) {
            ((MainenanceApplication)getApplication()).setDataStructure(param);
            loading.dismiss();
            //((BuildingAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            setListAdapter(new BuildingAdapter(BuildingSelectionActivity.this));
        }

    }.execute();
}
```

This works as it's supposed to, but my question is in onPostExecute I update the datastructure that the list adapter uses.
Why cant I just call notifyDataSetChanged ??

If I have that line the view does not update itself, but if I use the line under where I do setListAdapter, it all works.

Comment: It could be better that you put the code that shows how you are using notifyDataSetChanged() to update the List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the adapter is already set, setting it again will not refresh the listview. Instead first check if the listview has a adapter and then call the appropriate method.

I think its not a very good idea to create a new instance of the adapter while setting the list view. Instead, create an object.

```
BuildingAdapter adapter = new BuildingAdapter(context);

    if(getListView().getAdapter() == null){ //Adapter not set yet.
     setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else{ //Already has an adapter
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) instead of an AsyncTask for this. It's this kind of stuff that [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) were exactly designed for. Note that even though Loaders weren't available until API-10 you can still easily access them via the android [Support Pacakge](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) from API-4 and up.

Answer (score 0):

The only place you can update the UI is in `onProgressUpdate(...);`. From your `doInBackground(...)`, call `publishProgress(...)`.