# Changing the Adapter at runtime

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I am using an adapter to display the result of a cursor on a separate screen in alphabetical order. The problem is I need to use an EditText field to filter the result.
When I do this with the filter adapter always gives error due to the index properties of each alphabetical letter which he must redo. So I thought I'd change the adapter to a simple, no alphabetical division only when the user makes the filter for the search field.
I leave the original adapter and the adapter without a filter to search I add the filter that will run another cursor. This exchange of Adapter at runtime given problem: when I change the X Adapter (without filterqueryprovider) for the Y-Adapter (with filterqueryprovider) works normal .. but when the reverse is true filterqueryprovider just running in the X Adapter and the result of the cursor does not appear. How to solve this problem?

See the code below the adapter and my Activity

Adapter:

```
/**
 * CursorAdapter that uses an AlphabetIndexer widget to keep track of the section indicies.
 * These are the positions where we want to show a section header showing the respective alphabet letter.
 * @author Eric
 *
 */
public class OrdemAlfabeticaAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer{

private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 1;
private static final int TYPE_NORMAL = 0;

private static final int TYPE_COUNT = 2;

private AlphabetIndexer indexer;

private int[] usedSectionNumbers;

private Map<Integer, Integer> sectionToOffset;
private Map<Integer, Integer> sectionToPosition;
private Context context;

public OrdemAlfabeticaAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String coluna,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    this.context = context;

    indexer = new AlphabetIndexer(c, c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(coluna), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    sectionToPosition = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(); //use a TreeMap because we are going to iterate over its keys in sorted order
    sectionToOffset = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    final int count = super.getCount();

    int i;
    //temporarily have a map alphabet section to first index it appears
    //(this map is going to be doing somethine else later)
    for (i = count - 1 ; i >= 0; i--){
        sectionToPosition.put(indexer.getSectionForPosition(i), i);
    }

    i = 0;
    usedSectionNumbers = new int[sectionToPosition.keySet().size()];

    //note that for each section that appears before a position, we must offset our
    //indices by 1, to make room for an alphabetical header in our list
    for (Integer section : sectionToPosition.keySet()){
        sectionToOffset.put(section, i);
        usedSectionNumbers[i] = section;
        i++;
    }

    //use offset to map the alphabet sections to their actual indicies in the list
    for(Integer section: sectionToPosition.keySet()){
        sectionToPosition.put(section, sectionToPosition.get(section) + sectionToOffset.get(section));
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (super.getCount() != 0){
        //sometimes your data set gets invalidated. In this case getCount()
        //should return 0 and not our adjusted count for the headers.
        //The only way to know if data is invalidated is to check if
        //super.getCount() is 0.
        return super.getCount() + usedSectionNumbers.length;
    }

    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_NORMAL){//we define this function in the full code later
        //if the list item is not a header, then we fetch the data set item with the same position
        //off-setted by the number of headers that appear before the item in the list
        return super.getItem(position - sectionToOffset.get(getSectionForPosition(position)) - 1);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
    if (! sectionToOffset.containsKey(section)){ 
        //This is only the case when the FastScroller is scrolling,
        //and so this section doesn't appear in our data set. The implementation
        //of Fastscroller requires that missing sections have the same index as the
        //beginning of the next non-missing section (or the end of the the list if 
        //if the rest of the sections are missing).
        //So, in pictorial example, the sections D and E would appear at position 9
        //and G to Z appear in position 11.
        int i = 0;
        int maxLength = usedSectionNumbers.length;

        //linear scan over the sections (constant number of these) that appear in the 
        //data set to find the first used section that is greater than the given section, so in the
        //example D and E correspond to F
        while (i < maxLength && section > usedSectionNumbers[i]){
            i++;
        }
        if (i == maxLength) return getCount(); //the given section is past all our data

        return indexer.getPositionForSection(usedSectionNumbers[i]) + sectionToOffset.get(usedSectionNumbers[i]);
    }

    return indexer.getPositionForSection(section) + sectionToOffset.get(section);
}

@Override
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    int i = 0;      
    int maxLength = usedSectionNumbers.length;

    //linear scan over the used alphabetical sections' positions
    //to find where the given section fits in
    while (i < maxLength && position >= sectionToPosition.get(usedSectionNumbers[i])){
        i++;
    }
    return usedSectionNumbers[i-1];
}

@Override
public Object[] getSections() {
    return indexer.getSections();
}
//nothing much to this: headers have positions that the sectionIndexer manages.
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == getPositionForSection(getSectionForPosition(position))){
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    } 
    return TYPE_NORMAL;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return TYPE_COUNT;
}

//return the header view, if it's in a section header position
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (type == TYPE_HEADER){
        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
//              convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false); 
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cabecalho_divisao_alfabetica, parent, false); 
        }
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.header)).setText((String)getSections()[getSectionForPosition(position)]);
        return convertView;
    }
    return super.getView(position - sectionToOffset.get(getSectionForPosition(position)) - 1, convertView, parent); 
}


//these two methods just disable the headers
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_HEADER){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public AlphabetIndexer getIndexer() {
    return indexer;
}

}
```

My Activity:

```
public class BuscaProprietarioActivity extends ListActivity {

private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter1;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter2;
private EditText filterEditText;
private LinearLayout viewNenhumRegistroEncontrado;
private LinearLayout viewResultado;
private final String[] colunas = new String[] { ProprietarioProvider.Columns.ID, 
        ProprietarioProvider.Columns.NOME, ProprietarioProvider.Columns.TELEFONE };
private Cursor cursor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.proprietario_busca);

    filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.busca_proprietario_campo_busca);
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      String s = "'%" + query + "%'";
      String selection = ProprietarioProvider.Columns.NOME + " LIKE " + s;
      cursor = cr.query(ProprietarioProvider.CONTENT_URI, colunas, selection, null, 
                ProprietarioProvider.Columns.NOME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    } else {
        cursor = cr.query(ProprietarioProvider.CONTENT_URI, colunas, null, null, 
                ProprietarioProvider.Columns.NOME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    }


    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        viewResultado = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.busca_proprietario_resultado);
        viewResultado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        adapter1 = new OrdemAlfabeticaAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_proprietario, 
                cursor, ProprietarioProvider.Columns.NOME, new String[]{ProprietarioProvider.Columns.NOME, 
                ProprietarioProvider.Columns.TELEFONE}, 
                new int[]{R.id.list_item_proprietario_nome, R.id.list_item_proprietario_telefone});
        setListAdapter(adapter1);

        adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
                R.layout.list_item_proprietario, cursor, new String[]{ProprietarioProvider.Columns.NOME, 
            ProprietarioProvider.Columns.TELEFONE}, 
            new int[]{R.id.list_item_proprietario_nome, R.id.list_item_proprietario_telefone});
        adapter2.setFilterQueryProvider(filterQueryProvider);

        filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.busca_proprietario_campo_busca);
        filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);



    } else {
        // mostra tela de registro nao encontrado
        viewNenhumRegistroEncontrado = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.busca_proprietario_nenhum_registro_encontrado);
        viewNenhumRegistroEncontrado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}

private FilterQueryProvider filterQueryProvider = new FilterQueryProvider() {
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
        String selection = ProprietarioProvider.Columns.NOME + " LIKE '"+constraint+"%'";
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(ProprietarioProvider.CONTENT_URI, colunas, selection, null, 
                ProprietarioProvider.Columns.NOME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

        return cursor;
    }
};

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        if (s != null && s.length() > 0) {
            setListAdapter(adapter2);
            getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            adapter2.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(false);
        } else {
            setListAdapter(adapter1);
            getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};  

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have already set your adapter, setting it again won't update the UI. you will need to use the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7920243/563306

Comment: dcanh121, I tried using the notifyDataSetChanged () but did not work. When return from the adapter2 to adapter1 the view does not show anything.

Comment: Resolved. The problem was that I was using the same Cursor object in two Adapters. I just created a new Cursor object to Adapter2. =]