# Recreate same Listview on item click

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have a `Listview` and is working well. I'm getting `JSON` data from remote server and using `SimpleAdapter`. Basically I get song list from the server. But now, I want to let user select category first. After selecting any category I want to change the `URL` depending on the selected category, and then populate the listview again. Like, I'm calling `getlist.php` to get categories. Now if user selects a category named `POP`, want to call `getlist.php?cat=pop` to get all pop songs and re-populate the listview where user will see a list of pop songs.

```
private static String url_json = "http://10.0.2.2/aaa/getlist.php"; //this gives only the categories
private static String url_json = "http://10.0.2.2/aaa/getlist.php?cat=pop"; //this gives all songs those are under category pop
```

I don't think code is necessary here, if you still need please tell me, I'll update with code given.

Till now I used the following code in `onItemClick` but not working:

```
categorySelected = true;
url_json += "?c=Bangla";
new LoadAllProducts().execute();
lv.invalidateViews(); //final ListView lv = getListView();
```

So, let me summerise the full thing. On category item click, I want to change the `URL` I'm getting data from, and refresh the `Listview` with new data. Thanks in advance.

**Code:** Please have a look at my code and suggest any change.

```
public class AllRBT extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    //private static String url_all_products = "http://aloashbei.com.bd/vasonapps/getList.php";
    private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/aaa/getlist.php";
    private static Boolean categorySelected = false;
    private static String confTitle = "Confirmation needed !";
    private static String confBody = "We want to send message from next time you select any ring back tone. This may cost 15 taka by your network operator.";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "rbts";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "code";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_ARTIST = "artist";
    private String mobileNumber = "";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    private EditText inputSearch;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    //ListAdapter adapter;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
    private void getMobileNumber(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle(confTitle);
        alert.setMessage(confBody);//Are you sure want to buy this ring back tones?

        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        //final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        //alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          //String m = input.getText().toString();
          // Do something with value!
          mobileNumber = "017";

          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
              mobileNumber = "";
          }
        });
        alert.show();
    }

    public String[] generateMessage(String number, int code){
        String opCode = number.substring(0, 3);
        String messageBody = "", destination = "";
        String[] returnValue;
        if(opCode.equals("015")){
            messageBody = "TT "+code;
            destination = "5000";
        }else if(opCode.equals("017")){
            messageBody = "WT "+code;
            destination = "4000";
        }else if(opCode.equals("019")){
            messageBody = ""+code;
            destination = "2222";
        }else if(opCode.equals("016")){
            messageBody = "CT "+code;
            destination = "3123";
        }else if(opCode.equals("018")){
            messageBody = "GET  "+code;
            destination = "8466";
        }else if(opCode.equals("011")){
            messageBody = "Get"+code;
            destination = "9999";
        }else{
            messageBody = "Invalid number";
        }

        return new String[] {messageBody, destination};
    }

    private void sendMessage(String dest, String body, String popupText){
        if(popupText != "")
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), popupText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(dest, null, body, null, null);
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_rbt);

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_rbt);
        //filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
        //filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                //android.R.layout.list_content, 
                //getStringArrayList());

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        //filter listView
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {             
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3){
                // When user changed the Text
                AllRBT.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }             
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
        });

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        final ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                //lv.invalidateViews();

                //if(false){
                    categorySelected = true;
                    url_all_products += "?c=Bangla";
                    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
                    lv.invalidateViews();
                //}

                //Context context = getApplicationContext();
                String[] values;
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();
                if(mobileNumber == ""){
                    getMobileNumber();
                    return;
                }


                values = generateMessage(mobileNumber, Integer.parseInt(pid));
                String popup = "Sending message '"+values[0]+"' to "+values[1];
                sendMessage(values[1], values[0], popup);
                //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                //toast.show();
            }
        }); 
    }


    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllRBT.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading ring back tones. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            //toast.show();

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);


            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            //Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = 1;//json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1){
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String artist = c.getString(TAG_ARTIST);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_ARTIST, artist);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                      //      NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    //startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    AllRBT.this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllRBT.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID, TAG_NAME, TAG_ARTIST}, new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.artist });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the (very minimal) few lines of code you've provided you are loading stuff into your `List` that is backing your `ListView` from an `AsyncTask` (LoadAllProducts?). If that is the case, be sure to update your ListView's data in the `onPostExecute()` method you should override, and call something like `notifyDataSetChanged()` when you finished updating.

For more info on how to use AsyncTasks, check the great number of answers on this topic on SO. For instance, I put an answer with some info on AsyncTasks here: [progress dialog is not displaying in async task when asynctask is called from separate class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966343/progress-dialog-is-not-displaying-in-async-task-when-asynctask-is-called-from-se/13968941#13968941)

**Update after code was added:**

OK, I never used a `ListActivity` before, but after reading some documentation I think the problem is that calling `setListAdapter()` a second time will not refresh the ListView (as was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919691/notifydatasetchanged-on-my-adapter-does-not-update-the-listview-why)). Instead of creating a new `SimpleAdapter` every time I think you should update your `productList` (clear it, add to it, whatever you want) and then call `AllRBT.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. This should trigger the `ListView` to re-fetch the data from your adapter, which by now contains your new data.

Also some other remarks that will make your code cleaner:

1. you need not call `runOnUiThread()` from `onPostExecute()`, since `onPostExecute()` is guaranteed to run on the main thread already (as per `AsyncTask` contract).
2. I think you don't need to add an `OnItemClickListener` by yourself. It seems that a `ListActivity` already does that for you and you can instead simply override its `onListItemClick()` method.

Comment: Thank you for this, I've got an idea.